# Automate Email Message Text Dependent on Text Box value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send an email through VBA that is populated with information from a userform, I can do this quite easily with the code that I have below,

The only problem I am having is some of the information is only required when it is a certain value in the form, for example, the colour will be standard as "Black" unless specified otherwise.

If the colour is set to "Black" in my userform I do not want to include it on the email, I only want it to show if they want another colour such as "White"

Is there an if statement that skips the whole line and continues the email if the text box is "Black" and will only include it on the email if it something other than black?

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = csemail_txt.Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Quote Reference: " & Quotenum_txt.Value
    .Body = "Hello" & csname_txt.Value & vbNewLine & _
    "Thank you for your enquiry, please find your quote below: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Product Code: " & ProductCode_Combo.Value & vbNewLine & _
     "Dimensions: " & dimension_txt.Value & vbNewLine

    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

minor correction ;-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by: **include it in the email**. Are you talking about Font colour or background or maybe some other form of colour?

Comment: Why not prepare the body text in a string depending on the color?

Comment: @Zac Sorry for not being very clear, I do not mean the colour of the text or the background. What I want is for the customer to be able to decide whether they want a black skateboard or a white skateboard but I only want the colour of the skate board to be included on the email if it is a white skateboard, the email itself is a specification of a product. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub OutStr()
ColorStr = "white"

BodyStr = "Hello " & csname_txt.Value "!" & vbNewLine

If ColorStr = "black" Then
    'We don't talk about the color if the color is black ;-)
    'see https://www.google.com/search?q=henry+ford+color+black
    'BodyStr = "The color will be black as you know!"
Else
    BodyStr = BodyStr & "The color will be " & ColorStr & " as requested!" & vbNewLine
End If

BodyStr = BodyStr & "Your Board will have " & NrOfWheels & " wheels as requested!" & vbNewLine

if feature1 then BodyStr = BodyStr & "Let's talk about feature 1!" & vbNewLine
if feature2 then BodyStr = BodyStr & "Let's talk about feature 2!" & vbNewLine
if feature3 then BodyStr = BodyStr & "Let's talk about feature 3!" & vbNewLine

MsgBox BodyStr
End Sub
```

Comment: So I have tried this code and changed the names of my boxes but I get an error, I am trying to put this into my existing code at the top and it is showing "Compile Error: Expression Expected" I think your code would work if this was the only thing I was trying to put in the email?

Comment: Hi, this works for one outcome, in my code I want to have multiple variables such as color white or black but then also maybe something like, 4 wheels or 5 wheels, if this is possible, I just need more than one IF hope that makes sense?

Comment: Depending on the text and the number of variables you might want to change your code accordingly. I will update the above answer.